# Using algorithms with integer ranges

Tags: c++

Is it any nice way to call STL algorithms on an integer range?

For example I have a collection "col" with access to it's elements only via GetElement(int) method. Is it possible to use find_if function to find something in that collection?

I would like to call something like that:

```
auto element = 
        find_if(0, col.Size(), [&col] (int i) { 
            return predicate(col.GetElement(i));
        });
```

I'm looking for an STL or any other library solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard C++? Yes, if you write a custom element iterator.  Then, your code is easily simplified to:

```
auto element = find_if(col.begin(), col.end(), predicate);
```

---

It's not possible to do something closer to what you had in mind with the standard library, but it is with Boost, which is an incredible C++ library that you really ought to have.  Boost has a counting iterator: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html

> How would you fill up a vector with the numbers zero through one hundred using std::copy()? The only iterator operation missing from builtin integer types is an operator*() that returns the current value of the integer. The counting iterator adaptor adds this crucial piece of functionality to whatever type it wraps. One can use the counting iterator adaptor not only with integer types, but with any incrementable type.

```
#include <boost\counting_iterator.hpp> //or something, not sure of exact header

int main() {
    boost::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
    boost::counting_iterator<int> last(col.Size());
    auto element = find_if(first, last, [&col](int i) {return predicate(col.GetElement(i);});
}
```

Additionally, boost also has ranges.  They don't really help you much in this *exact* situation, but it's related, so I'll mention it:

```
#include <boost\range\irange.hpp>

int main() {
    for (int index: boost::range::irange<int>(0, col.Size()) ) 
    {
        std::cout << element; //counts from 0 to col.Size()
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if you implement iterator?

Comment: Sure, you could rewrite `boost::counting_iterator` yourself, but why would you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55345/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-bits-international).